# Get the last element of a list in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm following an introduction to Computer Science using Scheme. I am into the following problem, and I come up with a solution, it seems however that I'm lost in the syntax.

Define a procedure last-pair that returns the list that contains only the last element of a
given (nonempty) list:
(last-pair (list 23 72 149 34))

Here is my solution:

```
   (define (last-pair array) 
     ((define (get-last (length array) array)) 
       (if (= (length array) 1) (car array) 
        (get-last (- 1 (length array)) (cdr array))))))
```

Here is the mistake: Error: Invalid lambda: (lambda ((length array) array))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in:

```
(define (get-last (length array) array)
```

When you define a function, you have to list the function name and its arguments:

```
(define (function-name arg1 arg2 ... argN) ...
```

`(length array)` can't be an argument: it's a call to a function.

Anyway, there is no need to define `get-last`. Something like this is enough:

```
(define (last-pair array) 
  (if (= (length array) 1) 
      array
      (last-pair (cdr array))))
```

Comment: I would discourage the use of `length`. `length` is a nasty habit to get into.

Comment: I agree. I just kept the initial approach. In this case, probably, the simplest thing would be something like `(car (reverse array))`

Answer (score 3):

In your procedure you are calling a definition..

```
+   ; ==> <procedure: +> (how it's printed varies but it  is the value that can be called)
(+) ; ==> 0 
^- this calls the result for evaluation `+` which is `<procedure: +>`

((define something ...)) ; == (undefined-value) == Error!
^- this calls the result of `(define something ...)`.
```

`define` will return some implementation dependent value and in the report it's just says it's undefined. You cannot assume it's the same as value that `something` is bound to (which would be a nice undefined value)

Also the format of your local `define` uses no standard extensions that might be ok for some Scheme implementations and it's defined in [SRFI-16](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-16/srfi-16.html), but it's not a portable feature.

```
(define (get-last (length array) array)
  ...)
```

Thus in a language that does not allow this you would get an error while languages that supports the extension might not.

The difference between the last pair and the pair before it is the value of the `cdr`. `(cdr '(1 . 2)) ; ==> 2` while `(cdr '(0 1 . 2)) ; ==> (1 . 2)`. Thus you can iterate the list until you hit a non `pair?` value for `cdr`:

```
(define (last-pair lst)
  (if (pair? (cdr lst))
      (last-pair (cdr lst))
      lst))

(last-pair '(1 2 3 4 . 5)) ; ==> (4 . 5)
```

Notice this will fail if you don't give it a pair to start with, just as `car` and `cdr`.